# Use a returning value from an INSERT table (A) into another table (B)

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I need to use the returning value of the Table A (ID) and insert it in Table B as a parameter:

```sql
insert into tableA (ID, Name , Address) 
values (GEN_ID(GENERATOR,1),'John','123 street') 
returning ID
--Example: ID=159
    
insert into tableB (ID, TABLE_A_FK ) 
  values (GEN_ID(GENERATOR,1), 159)
```

Instead of entering the actual value 159, can I create like a variable (e.g. `declare ID int;`), and just pass the parameter?

Comment: Given you tagged this with Delphi, do you want to solve this in Delphi (that is, execute first statement, get returned ID, execute second statement passing the ID as a parameter)? Or do you want to execute it in one go?

Comment: unfortunately no, need to run it at once within 1 query. thx

Comment: just `create trigger` of an `after insert`  type `on tableA` which would automagically insert rows into `tableB` when `tableA` gets new rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this in a single statement, is to use [`EXECUTE BLOCK`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-execblock) (basically an anonymous one-off procedure). It uses the same syntax as normal stored procedures in Firebird.

You can do:

```sql
execute block
as
  declare id integer;
begin
  insert into tableA (ID, Name , Address) 
    values (GEN_ID(GENERATOR,1), 'John', '123 street') 
    returning ID
    into id;

  insert into tableB (ID, TABLE_A_FK) 
    values (GEN_ID(GENERATOR,1), :id);
end
```

If necessary, `execute block` statements can be parameterized, so you can use parameters to provide values (instead of hard coding them). See the link above for details.